# Random Forest in Python: Either Data Conversion warning or weird result?

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I currently try to run a random forest algorithm on a dataset of house sales.

Unfortunately, I am struggling to get the X and Y variables into the right dimensions.

At first, I want to include only 4 features (like bathrooms, bedrooms, square feet, ...) to predict the price (which is the first column).

If I run the code like below, I will get the following error:

> DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples,), for example using ravel().

That's a pretty clear statement, so I transformed my y variable (Train_TargetVar) through ravel:

> Train_TargetVar = np.ravel(Train_TargetVar, order='C')

The code is running through now, but it doesn't make any sense. 
The confusion matrix in the end looks like this:

```
 Confusion matrix  
[[1 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 ..., 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 1 0]]
```

I am afraid that there are now several thousands of rows / columns - and no meaningful result...

Would be great if anyone could give me a hint and/or tell me which part of my code I have to change.

```
# Load Libraries
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



dataset= pd.read_csv('kc_house_data.csv')


dataset = dataset.drop('id', axis=1)
dataset = dataset.drop('date', axis=1)
dataset = dataset.drop('zipcode', axis=1)
dataset = dataset.drop('long', axis=1)



cols = ['price', 'bathrooms', 'floors', 'bedrooms', 'sqft_living', 'sqft_lot', 'waterfront', 'view', 'condition', 'grade', 'lat', 'sqft_above']
dataset[cols] = dataset[cols].applymap(np.int64)





# Splitting Dataset
Train,Test = train_test_split(dataset, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 176)



Train_IndepentVars = Train.values[:, 1:5]
Train_TargetVar = Train.values[:, 0:1]


print(Train_IndepentVars.shape)
print(Train_TargetVar.shape)



##RF

rf_model =  RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=30,n_estimators=5)
rf_model.fit(Train_IndepentVars, Train_TargetVar)

predictions = rf_model.predict(Train_IndepentVars)




###Confusion Matrix

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

print(" Confusion matrix ", confusion_matrix(Train_TargetVar, predictions))


importance =  rf_model.feature_importances_
importance = pd.DataFrame(importance, index=Train.columns[1:5], 
                          columns=["Importance"])

print(importance)
```

Comment: Can you provide the data?

Comment: Provide dummy data that works with your code and fails in the same way, in case your data is sensitive/private.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sure, the dataset is https://www.kaggle.com/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction from Kaggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the warning you saw you can ignore to be honest, and is not related to your results.

Your code is working as expected, but you need to modify your approach. What you have done is tried to fit a classifier to a regression problem (as the target variable currently stands), i.e., you are using a `RandomForestClassifier` to predict `price`, where `price` can take on 4028 different values. The classifier will see this as 4028 classes [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...., 4027]. That's why you see the crazy sized confusion matrix, it's made a 4028x4028 matrix.

Instead, you should either:

1. Turn this into a *regression problem*
2. Modify your target variable to make it a manageable *classifying problem*

**1. Regression problem**

Here is your code modified to use a `RandomForestRegressor` and then looking at its performance using the R-squared metric

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('data/kc_house_data.csv')

drop_cols = ['id', 'date', 'zipcode', 'long']
feature_cols = ['bathrooms', 'floors', 'bedrooms', 
             'sqft_living', 'sqft_lot', 'waterfront', 'view', 
             'condition', 'grade', 'lat', 'sqft_above']
target_col = ['price']

all_cols = feature_cols + target_col

dataset = df.drop(drop_cols, axis=1)
dataset[all_cols] = dataset[all_cols].applymap(np.int64)

# split dataset for cross-validation
train, test = train_test_split(dataset, test_size=0.3, random_state=176)

# set up our random forest model
rf = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=30, n_estimators=5)

# fit our model
rf.fit(train[feature_cols].values, train[target_col].values )

# look at our predictions
y_pred = rf.predict(test[feature_cols].values)
r2 = r2_score(y_pred, test[target_col].values)
print('R-squared: {}'.format(r2))

# look at the feature importance
importance =  rf.feature_importances_
importance = pd.DataFrame(importance, index=feature_cols, columns=['importance'])
print('Feature importance:\n {}'.format(importance))
```

This will print out:

```
R-squared: 0.532308123273

Feature importance:
              importance
bathrooms      0.016268
floors         0.010330
bedrooms       0.017346
sqft_living    0.422269
sqft_lot       0.104096
waterfront     0.021439
view           0.037015
condition      0.025751
grade          0.279991
lat            0.000000
sqft_above     0.065496
```

You may already know, but just for clarity you can read about:

- RandomForestRegressor: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html
- R-squared: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination

**2. Classifying problem**

You can create your own classes by creating some price buckets. For example, bucket 1: 0 - $100,000, 2: $100,000 - $200,000, and so on. For now, I just gave it two classes:

```
# fake price classes, this is for later
target_binary = ['price_binary']
dataset[target_binary] = (dataset[target_col] > 221900).astype(int)
```

Then using the `RandomForestClassifier`:

```
# Using a Random Forest Classifier
# fit the classifier
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=30, n_estimators=5)
rfc.fit(train[feature_cols], train[target_binary])

# look at the feature importance
importance_c =  rfc.feature_importances_
importance_c = pd.DataFrame(importance_c, index=feature_cols, columns=['importance'])
print('Feature importance:\n {}'.format(importance))

# look at our predictions
y_pred_c = rfc.predict(test[feature_cols])
cm = confusion_matrix(y_pred_c, test[target_binary])
print('Confusion matrix:\n {}'.format(cm))
```

Which will print the following:

```
Feature importance:
              importance
bathrooms      0.018511
floors         0.011572
bedrooms       0.019063
sqft_living    0.455199
sqft_lot       0.113200
waterfront     0.026671
view           0.030930
condition      0.021197
grade          0.235906
lat            0.000000
sqft_above     0.067749

Confusion matrix:
 [[  92  155]
 [ 324 5913]]
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks for your great answer, I am stunned! Some days before, I understood the problem: Even tough the code might be right, the confusion matrix is worthless in this case. Probably I will go with the Random Forest Regression, as proposed by you. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ravel, this will bring you the same 1d array imeddiately:

```
Train_TargetVar = Train.values[:, 0]
```